# Is there a way to trigger a Logic App on a deletion of a record in an Azure SQL table?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to trigger a Logic App on a deletion of a record in an Azure SQL table?

I've checked the [SQL Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#triggers) and there is only `When an item is created` and `When an item is modified`, which gives me the C and U in CRUD, but sadly there isn't an out-of-the-box trigger for the D.

I can think of some awful way of polling to get record deletions, but I'm hoping that there is a cleaner solution that some bright person has come up with, however I've had no joy with the Google searching.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the **Azure Event Grid**.  Azure Event Grid allows you to easily build applications with event-based architectures. First, select the Azure resource you would like to subscribe to, and then give the event handler or WebHook endpoint to send the event to. Event Grid has built-in support for events coming from Azure services, like storage blobs and resource groups. Event Grid also has support for your own events, using custom topics.

I would suggest monitoring the resource group and triggering it off the deletion from the RG.  There is a tutorial that shows this same concept with a VM but you should be able to modify it to meet your needs with an Azure SQL DB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app

Comment: Sorry, don't see how this answers my question. My (limited) understanding of Event Grid presupposes there is a suitable Event Source, which emits the appropriate event, and I don't think Azure SQL does when a record is deleted from a table. But if there is, please point me at it !

Comment: You are correct (I answered before coffee this morning).  I read this as you wanted to capture the deletion of an Azure SQL DB, not table.   I will have to think on this some more.

Answer (score 0):

I added an on delete trigger which adds the id of the deleted record to a secondary table.  I have the logic app look for modifications on the secondary table.